# using PLSQL dbms_output.put_line output in a winform app

Tags: c#, winforms, plsql

I have a procedure in PLSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE printAllPeople (payment INTEGER)
IS
  sum_ number(6) := payment;
  name_ varchar(10);
  CURSOR listOfPeople IS
  select lastname
  from driver join
  (select driver.id as tempdid, sum(payment) as isum
  from report join driver
  on report.driverid = driver.id
  group by driver.id
  having  sum(payment) > sum_)
  on driver.id = tempdid;
BEGIN
  IF NOT listOfPeople%ISOPEN THEN
 OPEN listOfPeople;
  END IF;
  LOOP
 FETCH listOfPeople INTO name_;
 EXIT WHEN listOfPeople%NOTFOUND;
     dbms_output.put_line(name_);
 END LOOP;
END;
```

And I have a winform app that retrieves data from an Oracle DB.
is there any option to somehow use the "dbms_output.put_line" to show the output on my winform app?

Comment: The short answer is NO. Instead of that, you can add out parameters to you procedure.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it looks like you should be able to invoke DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE from your app to retrieve text written to DBMS_OUTPUT by your PL/SQL code. [Docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm). Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine to simply call a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION get_dbms_output(maxbytes IN NUMBER, buffer OUT VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
IS
    l_line VARCHAR2(255);
    l_done NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN LENGTH(buffer) + 255 > maxbytes OR l_done = 1;
        dbms_output.get_line(l_line, l_done);
        buffer := buffer || l_line || CHR(10);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN l_done;
END get_dbms_output;
/
```